# Text Inside a Jumbotron does not scale in xs size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, scale

I have a jumbotron which shows a post using database.
The jumbotron looks normal in lg md and sm sizes.
But in xs size the text inside moves towards the left edge.

This is how the image looks when in lg size :

[image]

This is how the jumbotron looks in xs size :

[image]

I am new to bootstrap.

Comment: can you post your fully code?

Comment: Are you missing `col-*-xs` on your tags within the jumbotron?